# Phonegap StatusBar notifications on closed Application

Tags: android, cordova, notifications, phonegap-build

I am creating a simple app thats only job is to inform the user if something has changed(something in the database). If something is changed the user gets a status bar notification.

I am using this plugin: https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications/tree/example.

It works perfectly if lets say I update database something manually from the application. But this wont be the way in the future. Is it possible to achieve this?

For example a user is not using the app at the moment and his wifi is offline. At that time I change something in the database. When the user turns the wifi on, he should get the news that something has been updated. Is this possible to do with phonegap?

Do I need to create some script? But how to execute it if the app is not being used?

Comment: You need a push notification and not a local notification for this kind of job.

Comment: @Dominykas55, you can also use an online service like [firebase](https://www.firebase.com/). I use it. It does exactly what you are describing.